# How to dynamically add anchor/href in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im new to jQuery and i'm trying to convert all my phone class to have an anchor with an href:

**What I have**

```html
<div class="phone">111-111-1111</div>
<div class="phone">666-555-4444</div>
```

**What I want**

```html
<div class="phone"><a href="tel:111-111-1111">111-111-1111</a></div>
<div class="phone"><a href="tel:666-555-4444">666-555-4444</a></div>
```

I am trying to do something like this, but I am pretty lost:

```
$('.phone').each(function(){
  $(this).wrapInner('<a name="???' + $(this).html() + '" />');
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think solution is there in your question only...

Have a look at this.

```
$('.phone').each(function(){
    $(this).wrapInner('<a href="tel:' + $(this).html() + '" />');
});​
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2c2cU/)** Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".phone").each(function(index, element){
    $(element).html($("<a></a>").attr("href", $(element).text()).text($(element).text()));
});
```

Comment: I was looking for the same logic to apply a dynamic URL to a paragraph element.  thanks.$('#pStoryURL').html('<a href=http://www.cnn.com>test</a>');

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$('.phone').each(function(){
   $(this).append('<a href="' + $(this).html() + '">'+$(this).html()+'</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Write this code like :

```
$('.phone').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<a href="tel:' + $(this).html() + '">'+$(this).html()+'</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.phone').each(function(){
  $(this).html('<a name="???' + $(this).html() + '" href="tel:'+$(this).html()+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a>');
});
```