# Jquery - Wrap phone numbers into an anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html

I want to wrap all phone numbers in a webpage into an anchor tag using Jquery. The contents in the webpage are generated dynamically. That's why i cant do it in the html content directly. So i want to wrap all the phone number text into anchor tag.

Example:

Assume I have the following content in html:

```
<div>
   <span>
       47582 25541
   </span>
</div>
```

I want to convert it as:

```
<div>
   <span>
       <a href="tel:47582 25541">47582 25541</a>
   </span>
</div>
```

How can I do this, please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically add anchor/href in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470240/how-to-dynamically-add-anchor-href-in-jquery)

Comment: No thats not right for my solution, Here I have no identifier for the phone number text. I want to match the phone numbers not by class name or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Loop each element, grab it's value and convert to the anchor tag.

```
$('.phone_text').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<a href="tel:' + value + '">' + value + '</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using following way

```
$('.phone_text').each(function(){
    $(this).wrapInner('<a href="tel:' + $(this).html() + '" />');
});
```

Or using span.

Note: But it will effect all span. Don't suggest following.

```
$('span').each(function(){
    $(this).wrapInner('<a href="tel:' + $(this).html() + '" />');
});
```

Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470240/how-to-dynamically-add-anchor-href-in-jquery)

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/478jo3zf/)

Comment: You can match number this way `if($(this).text().match(/[0-9]+/g))`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 $('.phone_text').each(function(){
       var ph = $(this).text();
       $(this).html($('<a>').text(ph).attr('href',"tel:"+ph));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.phone_text').html('<a href="tel: ' + $.trim($('.phone_text').text()) + '"> ' + $('.phone_text').text() + '</a>');
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3vdwowre/

Answer (score 0):

**Key Points**

- The contents in the webpage are generated dynamically
- no identifier for the phone number text

**jQuery Plugin**

I've used jQuery plugin `livequery` from [here](https://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/)

Which will convert all existing and **dynamic** `<span>` to anchor tag

**Assumption**

`phone number` is wrapped in `<span>` with numbers and space

**Code**

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("span").livequery(function() {
    var self = $(this),
      text = self.text();

    // numbers & space 
    if (/[\d ]/.test(text)) {
      self.wrapInner($("<a>", {
        href: "tel:" + text
      }));
    }
  });

  // demo purpose only
  $("a").click(function() {
    $(".container").append($("<span>", {
      text: "1234 5678"
    }));
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hazzik/livequery/master/dist/jquery.livequery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#">Generate phone number</a>

<div class="container">
  <span>2345 6789</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have more elements with phone numbers:

```
/* All phone numbers to href */
var regex = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/;
$('div span').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    text = text.replace(regex, "<a href=\"tel:$&\">$&</a>");
    $(this).html(text);
});
```