# How to dynamically add anchor/href in jQuery that includes jinja2 value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jinja2, anchor

I have checked out [How to dynamically add anchor/href in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470240/how-to-dynamically-add-anchor-href-in-jquery) but to no avail.

How do I dynamically add the following anchor element using jQuery?

```
<a href="{{url_for('user.create')}}">Register</a>
```

I have tried the following:

```
$("#mySidenav").append('<a id="sideNavItem1" href="' + '{{url_for("user.create")}}' + ">Register User</a>");
```

but doesn't work.

It's really tricky with the quotes and jinja2 curly braces.

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: *doesn't work* - what *does* it do?  Does it fail to create the anchor?  Are there any messages in the console?  Does it create the anchor, but with the href as `{{url_for...`?  Is your js in your html file or in a .js file?  Is it parsed by [tag:jinja2] or entirely client side?

Comment: I have decided to `show` and `hide` the hard-coded anchor elements depending on the user selection.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the poster has chosen an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
const sideNav    = document.getElementById('mySidenav')
const url        = url_for('user.create') //the URL address
const anchor     = document.createElement('a')
anchor.innerText = 'Register'
anchor.setAttribute('href', url)
sideNav.appendChild(anchor)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please "edit" to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: While there's increasingly no need for jquery, it's still used in larger projects that already have jquery.  OP has *explicitly* asked for a jquery solution: *using jQuery*

Comment: I have decided to `show` and `hide` the hard-coded anchor elements depending on the user selection.